# android camera2 preview data stop callback in the middle of the call

Tags: android, android-camera2, no-data

My device is: [android camera2 Lollipop] Nexus 5

I used ImageReader to capture camera2 data. The data callback for a while, but no data later.

> Log : 
>   12-06 05:49:01.406 E/mm-camera(  202): cpp_module_util_handle_frame_drop:510, sending buffer stall, frmid:634, iden:0x20002
>   12-06 05:49:01.406 E/mm-camera(  202): cpp_module_util_handle_frame_drop:510, sending buffer stall, frmid:634, iden:0x20003
>   12-06 05:49:01.482 E/QCamera3HWI(  189): void qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::handleMetadataWithLock(mm_camera_super_buf_t*): Buffer stall observed reporting error
>   12-06 05:49:01.483 E/QCamera3HWI(  189): void qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::handleMetadataWithLock(mm_camera_super_buf_t*): metadata is NULL
>   12-06 05:49:01.483 E/CameraDevice-JV-1( 3294): Lost output buffer reported for frame 630
>   12-06 05:49:01.483 E/CameraDevice-JV-1( 3294): Lost output buffer reported for frame 630
>   12-06 05:49:01.514 I/SQ      ( 3294): PID[3294]TID[3395]:[SQ] INFO: SQCpu -  sq=35 total=54 c

Comment: Hey Iven, it's a great idea to post your code. So that it's easier for the other members to help you out. :)

Comment: It's more like caused by Qcom Platform not support well about camera2 ?

Comment: more like caused by android HAL camera2 code . :
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/impl/CameraDeviceImpl.java#onCaptureErrorLocked.

Camera has encountered an error producing an image buffer for a single capture, it cause no data received at client side .